# How to execute a list of vim commands on a text file?

Tags: vim

I have a text that's around 1000 lines long, and I have a bunch of vim commands I want to apply to it. Lots of regex find-and-replace stuff. For example:

- `:%s/^[^\$\$]/def`
- `:%s/\$\$/`
- `%s/='/ = ['`

I could copy and paste those commands one by one, but that's work I'll have to do again every time I receive a new version of this file. I'm wondering if there's a way to save a long list of commands that I can then apply to the file? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

#### registers

You can put them all into a *register*, either by typing those commands in a scratch buffer and then `y`anking into a register, or via explicit assignment:

```
:let @a = "%s///\n%s///"
```

Then, execute via `:@a`

Depending on your Vim configuration, the register contents may persist across sessions (cp. `:help viminfo`), but you must be careful to not override them.

#### scripts

A longer-lasting and more scalable solution is putting the commands into a separate script file, ideally with a `.vim` extension. You can put them anywhere (except `~/.vim/plugin`, unless you want them executed automatically), and then run them via

```
:source /path/to/script.vim
```

#### custom commands

If you need a set of commands very often, you can give them a name and turn them into a *custom command*:

```
:command! MyCommands %s/// | %s///
```

Put this into your `~/.vimrc`, or (if it's filetype-specific), make it a `:help ftplugin`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can run vim command from the shell using

`vim -c YourCommandHere`

Comment: So you're saying I could write a bash script that executed vim commands on a file, sequentially?

Comment: Yes, you can call vim command in a bash script.
Do not hesitate to check the vim man page, it is well explained.